# (Python) How to get full frame in openCV and convert it to string?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I try to send frame-data from webcamera trough websocket, but frames looks like similar to this:

```
[[1 2 3]
[3 2 1]
[2 3 4]
...
[2 3 4]
[2 2 2]
[1 1 1]]
```

This is numpy matrix. How get full frame without this three dots?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 

np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')
```

Comment: Atleast for me on python3 with numpy 1.11.1 printing fails with `TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the solution to this lies in how numpy arrays are formatted and printed. Before printing the image array, all you have to do is:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
```

and then simply do the following

```
print img
```